# How to use multiple thread to generate data?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I try to generate data set using multiple threads

I tried to create a Runnable and a couple of Threads in the following

```
public class DataGenerator {

      static int currentRow = 0 ;
      static PrintWriter pw ;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("Test3.csv") ; 
        pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        pw.println("var1,var2,var3") ;    
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable()) ;
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable()) ;
    t1.start(); 
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

        pw.close();
        System.exit(0) ;
    }


}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable  {
    public void run () {
        for ( int i = DataGenerator.currentRow; i < 50000000; DataGenerator.currentRow ++ ) {
            DataGenerator.pw.println(i + ",19:05.1,some text");
            System.out.println(i);
            }
    }
}
```

However   is looping over o

I cant find out why

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait until child threads completed : Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939076/wait-until-child-threads-completed-java)

Answer (score 2):

Your parent thread is closing the PrintWriter `pw` before the child Threads `t1` and `t2` can use it to print.  You need to have your parent thread call `wait()` after you've started your child Threads.

You should review the answer to [How to make a Java thread wait for another thread's output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289434/how-to-make-a-java-thread-wait-for-another-threads-output) for some help.  You can use this information to discover how to solve this issue from a code-standpoint; it's fairly simple.

**Note:** you have edited your question since this answer was posted; the answer to the following question is even more relevant: [Wait until child threads completed : Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939076/wait-until-child-threads-completed-java)

Other useful SO questions with applicable answers that you should read:

- [A simple scenario using wait() and notify() in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536692/a-simple-scenario-using-wait-and-notify-in-java)
- [How to use wait and notify in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java)
- [Wait function in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517022/wait-function-in-java)
- [Java Wait Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054681/java-wait-function)
- [Wait() / notify() synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398845/wait-notify-synchronization)

See also [Java Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Answer (score 2):

When you start a thread it leaves the thread to start up in its own thread. So what is happening is, its starting the thread and then going straight to the next call `pw.close()` before the thread has had a chance to start up.